# Помогите до ума довести следущую небольшую программку на ассемблере

Tags: ассемблер

```
     Пусть имеет место следующее определение :

     LOST_A    DB   100 dup  (?) .

          Тогда следующий пример описывает поиск символа 'A' в блоке

     памяти длиной 100 байтов, начинающемся с LOST_A :

              MOV  AX,DS

              MOV  ES,AX     ;SCASB использует ES:DI,

                             ;поэтому копируем DS в ES

              CLD            ;сканировать будем в прямом направлении

              MOV  AL,'A'    ;ищем "потерянное" 'A'

              MOV  CX,100    ;сканировать будем 100 байтов

                             ;(CX используется в REPNE)

              LEA  DI,LOST_A ;засылаем стартовый адрес в DI

       REPNE  SCASB          ;ищем 'A'

              JE   FOUND     ;признак ZF равен 1, если мы нашли 'A'

     NOTFOUND:     .         ;если мы попали сюда,

                   .         ;то 'A' не обнаружено

                   .

        FOUND:DEC  DI        ;возвращаем указатель DI на первое

                   .         ;обнаруженное вхождение 'A'
```

Как я понимаю в меток FOUND и NOTFOUND должен быть конец или как? И если да, то как его поставить? К примеру NOTFOUND end не работает.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос то:

```
REPNE  SCASB        
jcxz FOUND 
    ; тут код если НЕ нашлось 
jmp  exit
FOUND:   
    ; тут код если нашлось 
exit:
```